# how to retrieve record of selected item of combobox in to the text box

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to show all details of the member through the name selected in combo box..Im trying below given code

```
private void cbSearchByName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //int RowsAffected = 0;
            DataAccess oDataAccess = new DataAccess();
            con.Open();
            //showing flat number of selected member by name
            oDataAccess.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FlatNo FROM MemberInfo where MemberName='" + cbSearchByName.Text + "'";
            oDataAccess.cmd.Connection = con;

            tbOwnerName.Text = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: So are you getting any exception? What happens when you run the code? what's the result. Actually, what's you question exactly?

Comment: that means on member details form by selecting the name of member through the combobox respective data of that name should be displayed in their respective textboxes...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to get all column records from memberinfo table and display them in UI. For that, you need to use ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteScalar. I have implemented execute reader in below code

```
private void cbSearchByName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        //int RowsAffected = 0;
        DataAccess oDataAccess = new DataAccess();
        using(SqlConnection connection = con )
      {
        connection.Open();
        //showing flat number of selected member by name
        oDataAccess.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Top 1 Name,City FROM MemberInfo where MemberName='" + cbSearchByName.Text + "'";
        oDataAccess.cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        tbOwnerName.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
        tbOwnerCity.Text = dr["City"].ToString();
        //similarly store other column values in respective text boxes or wherever you need to get it displayed.
    }
       }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

Comment: thanx for helping ...I tried your code but now when i select the name from combobox it showing msg like "the connection was not closed.connections current state is open" something like that

Comment: This error probably due to unable to execute code con.Close();
I'm not sure exactly as I dont any wrong in above code. please keep some break points at con.open() and con.close(), then check whether these statements are getting executed
Can you show me complete error message?